# How do I reset the terminal prompt?

Tags: configuration, terminal, dotfiles

When I power up the terminal it reads:

```
username at 34 in ~
```

Im not sure what the 34 refers to. Is there a way I can figure out what's going on? I had previously cloned a dotfile.

Answer (score 1):

It is really hard to answer this question because of the lack of information. For instance:

1. Which shell are you using: `bash`, `zsh`, ...?
2. Do you use a shell framework like Oh My ZSH! or
3. What was the dotfile you cloned?

Here is my guess. A possible cause of the problem may be in the dotfile: you have cloned a (let's say) `.bashrc` from somebody else having this prompt configuration and the operation has overwritten your `.bashrc`.

If you are using `bash`, try running `echo $PS1` to get the prompt configuration. Your prompt looks something like

`\u at \H in \w`

- `\u` is the username
- `\H` is the hostname (I'm guessing, I don't know what `34` stands for)
- `\w` is the working directory